# batch file to Delete X days old files exclude few files

Tags: batch-file

I want to delete X days old files from a directory but want to exclude a specific file (*exception). I am using below command, but seems it is not working for me.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('forfiles /p "%userprofile%\.." /d -180 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo @file"^|findstr /vig:"%userprofile%\exception.txt"') do echo rd /s /q "%%~a"
```

Comment: What's the content of `exception.txt`? Why are you using `rd` (delete directories) rather than `del` (delete files)?

Comment: Your question and comments specifically say you are targeting files but all your code is targeting directories.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ForFiles` you could use `RoboCopy`:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('RoboCopy "%UserProfile%\.." Null /L /MinAge:180 /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS /NP /NS /XF exception*') Do @Del "%%A"
```

*Enter `RoboCopy /?` at the Command Prompt for its usage information.*

---

After re-reading your question, together with your code, it isn't clear whether you're wanting to exclude files named, `exception*`, which is what my answer above does, or to exclude files as listed inside a file named `exception.txt`. If it's the latter then you'd need to build a string of your exclusions first to append to the `/XF` list.

If your file only contains a few relatively short exclusion masks then you may be able to do it like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "EX="
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%UserProfile%\exception.txt") Do (
    If Not Defined EX (Set "EX=%%A ") Else Call Set "EX=%%EX%%%%A ")
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('RoboCopy "%UserProfile%\.." Null /L /MinAge:180 /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS /NP /NS /XF %EX%') Do Del "%%A"
```

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. Rewriting my query "I need to delete files, directories and sub-directories from Temp Folder "C:/Temp" modifies X days back but to keep a file (Named as "C:/Temp/Exception.txt") which generates logfile"

Comment: I am not confused and neither am I changing my answer just because you've decided to expand your requirements after one week. I have answered your question, mark it as accepted then post a new question.